# ACL for structure with subsets and trigger to keep it clean

Tags: mysql, acl

On my system I have a structure similar to the directories and files in them.
Users can have access to individual "files" or the entire "directory". I want to make granting permissions to the directory delete records for any files in this directory (because now it will have access to everyone). What I mean is that after deleting access to the directory, there is no 'garbage' in the form of access to individual files.
I tried use trigger BEFORE INSERT but i can't do it properly.

I have table permission:

- ID
- user_id
- directory_id
- file_id

Maybe the permission table is incorrectly modeled?